# how can i set html pattern negate with length range?

Tags: javascript, regex, html

how can I set HTML pattern negate with length range?

```
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" title="Address length 4 to 30" placeholder="Your address.."required pattern="[^- &(%#$^).]*.{3,30}"></div> <div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: can someone guide me

Comment: whats you mean negate with length range?  limiting input length in 4 to 30 characters?

Comment: when i set pattern="[^- &(%#$^).]* works well but when set range .{3,30} not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue you have at the moment is that you are using the the `*` and `{3,30}` quantifiers at the same time. Try using `[^- &(%#$^).]{3,30}` instead.

Comment: this work thanks ,I need more help .will you help me?

Comment: I am wanted one space allow between each word in this pattern [^- &(%#$^).]{3,30}

Comment: You would need to use a group to do that. Maybe something like `[^-&(%#$^).]{3,30}( [^-&(%#$^).]{3,30})*`. The first `[^-&(%#$^).]{3,30}` matches the first word, and `( [^-&(%#$^).]{3,30})*` matches all other words. If you want to experiment with regular expressions, a site like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) might be able to help you.

Comment: its work well but i want to add one space allow between each word

Comment: its work well but i want to add one space allow between each word .(pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*$") this pattern work for only one space between words.can you merge this pattern into previous one

Comment: Combining the pattern in my original answer and the pattern you just provided shouldn't be too difficult. You should try looking up a regex tutorial and seeing if you can combine them yourself.

Comment: I tried but it did not work can you do it for me plz